Ubuntu Studio + XFCE broken update: Toolbar / app switcher icons are unresponsive
I (perhaps foolishly) accepted a system update the other day. Since then, once yesterday and twice today, the XFCE desktop just went belly up.
If I click on app badges in the toolbar, it either fails to respond, or acts like a right-click.
If I click an app's close button, nothing happens.
If I alt-tab to switch apps, nothing happens.
Reboot / logout menu doesn't open.
I can't even drop out of the X session into the background terminal.
The only thing that works is to hold down the power key for 10 seconds until the system goes down.
So... what to do next? If it's possible to roll back the update, that would help I guess? However my apt-fu is limited, so I'd need advice on how to find out what state the system was in, say, 4 days ago vs today and undo that.
In the meantime, KDE Plasma is also installed on this machine. I had quit using it because of other unstable behavior but for the moment, it may be an acceptable workaround.
In short, halp.
Linux dlm-21cx 5.15.0-91-lowlatency #101-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 16 14:17:44 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(Ubuntu Studio 22.04 running on a Lenovo Thinkbook 14")
More detail:

It may help if you're specific as to what you changed/installed on your initial 22.04 system (please respond via detail in question)

That initial installation was over a year ago, so I doubt my ability to provide a complete list of all changes.
As I recall, I used the Ubuntu Studio 22.04 ISO, and then sudo apt-get install xfce4 on top of that.
I had installed a bunch of gcc, *dev and Qt dev packages for building SuperCollider.
I use fcitx instead of ibus for Chinese character input.
I disable PulseAudio at startup, with this in /etc/pulse/client.conf:
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true

... then run it as a JACK client, launching Pulse in a qjackctl script. I can't imagine this would affect UI, though, especially since I've been using this configuration for, oh, 14 years.
I do notice in XFCE that apt package management GUIs aren't reliable -- seems to be some conflict with the Plasma package management interfaces. I've been installing updates by sudo apt-get upgrade -- generally no problem until this time.

It was a standard Ubuntu Studio 22.04 install with Plasma; I added XFCE packages over the top of this. (I now understand I shouldn't have done that; I should have installed Ubuntu 22.04 with XFCE first, and added Ubuntu Studio packages.) I haven't release-upgraded; this installation has always been 22.04. Unfortunately I haven't configured any apt backup strategy. I was hoping for some advice here to investigate apt history -- which packages updated? Is there a way to force those back to an older version?

Thanks, added detail.
